# Where am I wrong while populating Mongoose virtuals?

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have Account and User models.

```
var AccountSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
}

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    account: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Account'
    };
});
```

I want to populate users when querying the account. Therefore I implement this:

```
AccountSchema.virtual('users', {
    ref: 'User',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'account'
});
```

But I cannot see users field when I write:

```
Account.findOne({"_id": "568a8523c50d1e0300aed5d5"}).populate('users').exec(function(err, account){
            console.log(err);
            console.log(account);
        });
```

Mongoose version is 4.7.7.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Do you have an error or model doesnt have `users` prop?

Comment: Model doesn't have users prop

Comment: everything looks ok tho